# Run Powershell 7 from CMD

Tags: powershell

I have a .bat script that runs Powershell as Admin and then runs a Powershell script in the same folder as the .bat file. This works perfectly fine:

> CMD /C powershell "Set-Location -PSPath '%CD%'; $Path =
> (Get-Location).Path; Set-Location ~; Start powershell -Verb RunAs -Args
> "-ExecutionPolicy ByPass" Set-Location -PSPath '"$Path"'; &
> '".\Start_TOW_VM.ps1"'"""

I am now trying to use Powershell 7 (pwsh) instead and I thought it'd be as simple as changing to this:

> CMD /C pwsh "Set-Location -PSPath '%CD%'; $Path = (Get-Location).Path;
> Set-Location ~; Start pwsh -Verb RunAs -Args "-ExecutionPolicy
> ByPass" Set-Location -PSPath '"$Path"'; & '".\Start_TOW_VM.ps1"'"""

Unfortunately, it doesn't work and complains about the Set-Location command, even though that command works perfectly fine in Powershell 7. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post the exact error message

Comment: I can't post the error message because it disappears too quickly. You can easily test it yourself by creating a .bat file containing the command I posted. Then, create a .ps1 file with whatever you want to put inside. Run it with Powershell and with PWSH to get an idea of what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Change `cmd /c` to `cmd /k` to prevent `cmd.exe` from exiting immediately (so you can see and copy the error message)

Comment: The issue isn't related to cmd, it's powershell. CMD doesn't throw any errors, it's Powershell and it gets closed before I could do anything. Even using sleep and noexit didn't do anything. Please just run it on your end so you actually understand what the issue. It takes literally 2 mins for you to set this up.

Comment: I'm trying to help you obtain relevant troubleshooting information. Why are you refusing?

Comment: I'm not refusing anything. I'm simply telling you that CMD /K doesn't solve the issue here. I appreciate that you're trying to help, but sometimes it's important for you to understand the issue first, before throwing suggestions or answers that don't make sense. At this point, you're just guessing and not really looking at the right issue. As I've said, the issue is 100% unrelated to CMD /K or CMD /C.

Comment: I'm **not** suggesting that `cmd /k` solves the problem, I'm saying that using `cmd /k` will allow you to observe the exact error message from PowerShell for long enough to copy-paste it into your question... in turn giving myself (and anyone else) a better chance of understanding the issue.

Comment: Like I said, cmd /k doesn't work. I don't think you really understand what cmd /c and cmd /k does. All cmd /k does is it keeps cmd from closing, but it doesn't stop Powershell from closing. Again, you're not reading what I said earlier. Run the actual script yourself instead of guessing, then you'll see what I mean. At this point, you're just trying to troubleshoot this blindly. I've already shared the exact script you need, so you can test it directly on your end and look at the error first hand. Why are you making this complicated?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - to prove to you that you were completely wrong with your suggestions, THIS is the exact code that is throwing the error, specifically the Set-Location command. Change pwsh to powershell and it's fine - Start pwsh "-executionpolicy bypass -noexit set-location -pspath $Path"

Comment: Great to hear you managed to put together an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)! Please [add it to your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70846735/edit)

Comment: `CMD /C pwsh -c "Set-Location -PSPath '%CD%';Get-Location"`. **1st** Note the `-c` parameter (the same as `-Command`. **2nd** `CMD /C` is superabundant here.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - you do realize that the "MRE" is already part of the code posted in OP? Again, you don't bother reading and understanding the issue. You could very easily literally just run that code to look at the error. And again, completely unrelated to CMD /C or CMD /K. Please stop wasting people's time by pretending to help people, if you're not even going to spend the 10 seconds to run the code and understand the issue yourself.

Comment: @JosefZ - Thanks, that works, but it's the 2nd part that I'm having issues with - "start pwsh....". How do you replace the -args with -c in the 2nd part?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, here's the solution:

> CMD /C pwsh -c Set-Location -PSPath '%CD%'; $Path =
> (Get-Location).Path; Set-Location ~;write-host $path; start pwsh -Verb
> RunAs "-command Set-ExecutionPolicy ByPass;
> Set-Location -PSPath '"$Path"'; & '".\Start_TOW_VM.ps1"'"

Simply needed to add -command inside the escaped ".

Comment: This is a smart example of how to pass the current DOS working directory to PowerShell, then set this path in PowerShell as its own working directory :-)